# How to create Dashboard using Python or R

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.6, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

In my company, I have got task to create dash board using python whose complete look and feel should be like qlicksense. I am fresher in data science field I don't know how to do this. I did lots of R & D and plotly and dash is the best option as much according to R & D on internet dash table is also a good option but I am not able to create the things what it should look like. If any one know how to start plz help me ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use django or other web framework to develop the solution, 
keep in mind that you probably will need to handle lots of front end stuff like builiding the UI of the system, 
Flask also is very lightweight option, but it needs lots of customization.
Django comes with pretty much everything you might need out of the box.